# In Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, how did the other contestants defeat their dragons?

Tags: harry-potter

I don't recall the book or the movie ever stating how the other contestants defeated their dragons.
We know that Harry

> Used his wand to summon his broom to out fly the dragon

But how did the other contestants defeat their dragons?
What spells or techniques did they use?

I'm looking for a canon answer from the book or movie

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Conjunctivitis_Curse

Comment: Don't have the books with me or I'd quote the relevant sections, but Cedric tried to make it sleep (success, but slightly singed when the dragon woke up early), Fleur tried to charm it (likewise *mostly* successful, slightly less singed) and Victor used a Blinding Hex (technically successful, but the dragon smashed a lot of its own eggs while thrashing around in rage and pain)...

Comment: Sleeping curse;http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fleur_Delacour

Comment: @Shadur, even without quoting the relevant sections, you could still turn that comment into an answer.

Comment: Quick check of the wiki also shows I was off, but...

Comment: @djm - a bit of reasearch or google would have answered that question surely?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Harry’s dragon is last, so he doesn’t witness any of the other champions’s tasks directly. Instead, we learn about how they tackled them from Ron, as he explains it to Harry, after he finishes the task:

> “Cedric did this weird thing where he Transfigured a rock on the ground… turned it into a dog… he was trying to make the dragon go for the dog instead of him. Well, it was a pretty cool bit of Transfiguration, and it sort of worked, because he did get the egg, but he got burned as well – the dragon changed its mind halfway through and decided it would rather have him than the Labrador; he only just got away.
>
> “And that Fleur girl tried this sort of charm, I think she was trying to put it into a trance – well, that kind of worked too, it went all sleepy, but then it snored, and this great jet of flame shot out, and her skirt caught fire – she put it out with a bit of water out of her wand.
>
> “And Krum – you won’t believe this, but he didn’t even think of flying! He was probably the best after you, though. Hit it with some sort of spell right in the eye. Only thing is, it went trampling around in agony and squashed half the real eggs – they took marks off for that, he wasn’t supposed to do any damage to them.”
>
> — *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 20, *The First Task*

So Cedric used Transfiguration, Fleur used a sleeping charm and Krum attacked the eyes.

We learn the name of Krum’s spell  a bit later, when Sirius writes to Harry, and Hermione can’t help but interject:

> *Congratulations on getting past the Horntail. Whoever put your name in that goblet shouldn’t be feeling too happy right now! I was going to suggest a Conjunctivitus Curse, as a dragon’s eyes are its weakest point—*
>
> “That’s what Krum did!” Hermione whispered—
>
> — *Goblet of Fire*, chapter 23, *The Yule Ball*